# How to have reference to an item in a listView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i have a Listview with customised layout (TextView, Checkbox, and imageView), the customised ListView was set to the adapter that extends BaseaAapter.

the getView() method is posted below.

what i am trying to do is, when the imageView is touched, that item in the ListView should be deleted and `the adapter should be notified about the change`. in the mainActivity i used "OnItemClickListener" but i do not know how to get reference to the imageView that exists in the `getView()` method in the class the extends `Baseadapter`

How to get reference to `getView()` method from the mainActivity and based on the clickAction the item is deleted and the adapeter of the listView should be notified?

in other words,  if i ahve 5 items in the listView, if the imageView of the item number 3 is clicked then, the item 3 as whole should be deleted and the adapter should be notified by calling "notifyDatasetChanged()".

**OnItemClickListener**:

```
private OnItemClickListener listViewitemListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
};
```

**getView**:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items_layout, null);
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvlist_topic);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbList_hook);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivList_delete);

    tv.setText(this.arrayList.get(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: do u want to remove the ImageView from that layout Text/Check/Image or do you want to remove the whole entry from the list ?

Comment: just saw your edit, disregard my comment, I'll write the answer

Comment: the whole entry shoud be deleted from the list if the imageview is clicked and i want to notify the adapter about the change. for an example, if i ahve 5 items in the listView, if the imageView of the item number 3 is clicked then, the item 3 as whole should be deleted and the adapter should be notified.

Comment: actually, it depends. Where does your class that `extends BaseAdapter` get's the data from ? The basic idea is that your adapter have to return one less in the `getCount` and not give that position anymore. But `BaseAdapter` is abstract and it depends on how you implemented. I could write an answer for an `ArrayAdapter`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but if I did, you can resolve it like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items_layout, null);
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvlist_topic);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbList_hook);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivList_delete);

    tv.setText(this.arrayList.get(position));

    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //or View.GONE
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

EDIT: If you want to remove entire list item, use this instead:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items_layout, null);
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvlist_topic);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbList_hook);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivList_delete);

    tv.setText(this.arrayList.get(position));

    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            arrayList.remove(position);
            notifyDatasetChanged();
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: ok but setting the visibility of a view to INVISIBLE or GONE is as removing the item from the lisView. moreover, if i will use your answer how can i notify the listView adapter?

Comment: What do you mean by notify the adapter? There is a method `notifyDatasetChanged()` if that's what you're thinking of.

Comment: yes it is , but how can i call "notifyDatasetchanged2 while i am in getView(). and if i am in the mainActivity, how can i delete an entry based on if the imageview clicked or not?

Comment: i tried to call getAdapter() but such method is not existing

Comment: Sorry, that's the adapter itself, just call `notifyDatasetChanged()`, see editted answer.

Comment: Doesn't this just leak the entire list?

Comment: ok, but actually i am not convinced with changing  the visibility of the view and consider it as equivalent to removing item from the listView. i think removing item from a list view is different than changing its visibility. i am wrong?

Comment: @rmaik you are correct, but I didn't get what you wanted to do. The second part of the answer (below "EDIT") is for removing entire item from `ListView` the first part is for making the `ImageView` inside an item in `ListView` invisible.

Comment: so it is safe to consider  "view.INVISIBLE" equivalent to "listView.removeView(child)"?

Comment: Nope, `setVisibility(int visibility)` only changes the state of the `View` while `removeView(View child)` removes the `child` from the underlying dataset so you cannot reference it from `ListView` in the future.

Comment: ok that is what i want, i want to remove the view from the listView not changing its visibility. how can i do so